# doc/docx to pdf using jodconverter and OpenOffice

Tags: pdf, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I'm using [`jodconverter`](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) and [`OpenOffice 3.3`](http://www.openoffice.org/) to convert a docx file to pdf using the following command:

```
java -jar jodconverter-cli-2.2.2.jar test.docx test.pdf
```

It works fine when trying to convert most of the languages, but I can't convert docs written in Chines or Japanese. When doing so, I get gibberish instead of text:

[image]

I tried to install Japanese and Chines [OpenOffice language packs](http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/openoffice/packages/9/) as well as using [jodconverter 3.0 beta 4](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) but i got the same output.

### [Test file](http://rapidshare.com/files/1006876972/test.docx)

How can I add support for those languages?

Is there another tool (preferably opensource) i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=111292) in the OO version I was using. I got it to work by doing the following:

1. Update to latest OpenOffice.
2. Download the missing ttf files
3. Follow [this guide](http://www.smorgasbord.net/installing-windows-ttf-true-type-fonts-in-linux/) (or [this](http://minimallinux.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/centos-6rhel-install-fonts.html)) to installing Windows True Type Fonts in Linux

To make sure that the fonts are installed correctly, run:

```
fc-list
```

To search for a specific language, use `:lang=`. For example, for Hindi language:

```
fc-list :lang=hi
```

I got the conversion to work after adding the `MingLiU.ttf` font and the [baekmuk-ttf-fonts](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/18319463/dir/centos_6/com/baekmuk-ttf-fonts-common-2.2-28.el6.noarch.rpm.html) rpm package.